# How to get a Substring JAVASCRIPT?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, loops

I need to iterate over strings that are inside an array, to get a sub-string in each string.

Substrings are between "()"

Something like this..

```
let myArray = ["animal(cat)", "color(red)", "fruits(apple)"];

//return
//'cat','red','apple'
```

How I could do that?

Comment: Show us what code you have already written and where the problem you have comes in. Or are you just asking someone here to write it for you?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Here, you can learn [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) properly before you do so. When asking a question, be sure you are [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and always try to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when possible. This way, it's more likely volunteers on SO can help you.

Comment: What have you tried? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Methods_2 might contain something which would help you. Or maybe regular expressions would be better. Either way, this is not a free write-my-code service. We'll _help_ you, we won't _do it for you_. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using `substring` and `lastIndexOf` functions.

```js
let myArray = ["animal(cat)", "color(red)", "fruits(apple)"];

myArray.forEach(function(e){
    console.log(e.substring(e.lastIndexOf("(") + 1, e.lastIndexOf(")")))
})
```